# VB Webbrowser ProgressChange Altering

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control

```
Private Sub BusyTimer_Timer()
  If WebBrowser.Busy = True Then
    WebBusy.Caption = Chr$(BusyChr(BusyIdx))
    BusyIdx = IIf(BusyIdx >= UBound(BusyChr()), 0, BusyIdx + 1)
  Else
    ' Elements.AddItem "Busy Timer Ends"
    Me.Caption = WebBrowser.LocationName
    BusyTimer.Enabled = False
    ScanTimer.Interval = 10000
    ScanTimer.Enabled = True
  End If
End Sub
```

So I'm using the WebBrowser in an application and am trying to give indication that the browser is still busy fetching the webpage and this was my initial work of art in making it happen.
WebBusy is a Label on the form.
BusyChr() is the clocks from WingDings.

The issue with this is that if you click on a link while busy, order of precedence breaks the BusyTimer and it quits working.

So then I just moved this into the WebBrowser_ProgressChange event and have no problems with it.

But I find that the interval ProgressChange gets called is, slow.

Is there a means to change the interval?

Comment: If it's "classic VB" (i.e: Vb6)  please don't include a vb.net tag! I've no idea whether this would work, but have you tried adding a couple of DoEvents() into the code to allow the UI to update?

Comment: Could you add checks on other events like `BeforeNavigate2` or `NavigateComplete2` or `NavigateError` perhaps?  I don't know which one you would need, but if the first approach worked other than clicking a link, you likely could detect that the browser is navigating somewhere else mid-stream.